# How does str.upper() work in combination with map?

Tags: python

I found the following Python 3 code snippet on the web and I'm wondering why `str.upper` is working in this case:

```
my_pets = ['alfred', 'tabitha', 'william', 'arla']

uppered_pets = list(map(str.upper, my_pets))

print(uppered_pets)
```

Per definition `str.upper()`  does *not* take any parameters. So how does `map` know how to apply the elements in `my_pets` to the function in the first place? If I understand `map` correctly, it's only applicable to functions that take arguments but not to those like `upper()` that are used on strings directly, like for example `"abc".upper()`.

If I had to write that snippet, I would have done it this way:

```
my_pets = ['alfred', 'tabitha', 'william', 'arla']

uppered_pets = list(map(lambda s : s.upper(), my_pets))

print(uppered_pets)
```

However, I'd like to understand why and *how* the first snippet works, too.

Comment: Did you try calling `str.upper()`? It _does_ take (in fact, _requires_) an argument. It might help to know that you can call instance methods on the class by explicitly passing `self`, `"foo".upper()` -> `str.upper("foo")`.

Comment: I ran that first snippet in the very same form I posted above and strangely it worked somehow. According to the official Python documentary (https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) upper() does not take any arguemnts

Comment: When you call the method _on an instance_ it doesn't take any arguments. But you're calling it _on the class_.

Comment: You are mixing up `s.upper()` and `str.upper(self)`. The first is a call on an instance, the second is calling the method via the class `str`. This is true for class methods in general, you can always call them via the class and pass the `self` argument.

Comment: How do I see if it's a class method or not? You see, I'm moving from Java /C# to Python right now and I must say I'm having difficulties with the Python docs. Hardly any visual hints. In languages like Java, you can see right from the start what is a class method and what is an instance method.

Answer (score 0):

`str.upper` is infact a method of `str` class. And for each class or object, the first parameter it takes is `self`.

You don't pass any variable in `"foo".upper()"` because this is basically equal to `str("foo").upper()`.

`upper` will have some definition like this:

```
class str:
    def upper(self):
        # something
```